# Gateway time out in Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, bitbucket

When using mercurial to commit, I first get this error

```
files over 10MB may cause memory and performance problems
```

and then when finally try to push , I get a a gateway timeout

```
>hg push
http authorization required
realm: Bitbucket.org HTTP
user: kunjaan
password:
pushing to *
searching for changes
abort: HTTP Error 504: Gateway Time-out
```

Can anyone help me resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mercurial is not really made for adding such large files, have a look at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HandlingLargeFiles. There are two extensions linked on that page, that version the files but don't save them to the repository. I have no experience with them, but searching for it should give you more information.